# Use of Image() object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What's the use of declaring a variable as an image object in javascript

```
var img = new Image();
```

What's the use of the Image() object

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Comment: Very helpful to preload images or check if a url returns an image by using built in error handling before putting it in the page or check properties like size in a  load event listener. Is that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one word: **The `Image()` constructor provide you a way to manipulate an image in pragmatically way.** Suppose you need take some image modification based a radio button is checked or not then how can you do it? Also may need take few action  based image URL value, loaded or not etc in these cases `Image()` constructor is very handy. It will help you access their attributes as a object property as well. See below:

```
var image = new Image(100, 200);
image.src = 'profile-picture.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Above code is equivalent to: `<img width="100" height="200" src="profile-picture.jpg">`

`Image()` constructor also provide few handy methods to take the action based image status, see below:

```
image.onload = function(){
  // You can take action here when image loaded
}

image.onerror = function(){
   // You can take action here when image load failed
}
```

You can also take detail lesson from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Answer (score 0):

I have used this mostly to preload the images, this is what we need to preload an image.

```
function preloadImage(url)
{
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=url;
}
```